# Python: Confusing example of Functions as Objects

Tags: python, function, variables, python-decorators

When I was reasearching a bit about decorators, I stumbled upon some rather confusing code that i found perplexing in the way that it passes varibles and functions.

```
def get_text(name):
    return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)

def p_decorate(func):
    def func_wrapper(name):
        return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(name))
    return func_wrapper

my_get_text = p_decorate(get_text)

print my_get_text("John")

# <p>Outputs lorem ipsum, John dolor sit amet</p>
```

I understand the concept of passing functions as variables (which is cool) however the way that it was passed multiple times confused me. `my_get_text` has already been assigned to a function with an argument (another function). However, just after that we reference this new variable and pass arguments to it ("John"). The way that "John" gets transferred in `func_wrapper()` is also perplexing.

How is `my_get_text` able to receive more arguments and how is it passed to the inside functions?

Thank you

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code.  Indentation carries meaning in Python and in general can't be guessed.

Comment: What does `p_decorate()` return (once indentation has been corrected, of course)?

Comment: You also need to understand the concept of a _closure_ to fully appreciate what's happening in this example.

Comment: A function is not special when it comes to variable passing.  If `p_decorate` returned a number, you wouldn't be surprised that `p_decorate(get_text)` returned a number.  In the same way, it returns a function, and now `my_get_text` is a function and can be called as such.

Answer (score 2):

This is a demonstration of how decorators work: They basically wrap the decorated function into another internal function and return its reference.

1. In your example, the call `my_get_text = p_decorate(get_text)` calls the function `p_decorate` with the wrappable function as a parameter (`get_text`).
2. The return value is a reference to a newly defined function which takes exactly one parameter `name`. This return value is assigned to your variable name `my_get_text`
3. `my_get_text` is now *callable*, because it's a function reference.
4. If you call `my_get_text`, it calls the function that was created by the decorator and hands over your parameter `name` (in your case `'John'`).
5. The function creates `<p>`-Tags and pushes a string between them. This string is obtained from the function call that you provided the decorator in step 1: It is the return value of the call that has been *decorated*.

By the way, because the function `func_wrapper` is re-defined each time a function is decorated (see *closure*), the return value is a function reference that points to an entirely new function.
Compare the memory addresses:

```
a = p_decorate(get_text)
b = p_decorate(get_text)
print(a == b)
print(a)
print(b)

>>> False
>>> <function func_wrapper at 0x02ADFF30>
>>> <function func_wrapper at 0x02ADFF70>
```

The functions are defined with the very same call, but since they are *closures*, the function pointer refers to another memory address (i.e. a different function).